# Library data table - fread read multiple csv with encoding = "UTF-8

Tags: r

could you help? I do not know how to set parameter encoding = "UTF-8" in my function to read multiple CSV files:

```
library(data.table)
filenames <- list.files("C:/Users/H409126/OneDrive - Honeywell/R/Military/Cirium/Jan 2021/RawData",  #CHANGE
                        pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
cirium <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
library(data.table)
cirium <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread, encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

Or to be clear you can also use an anonymous function.

```
cirium <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames, function(x) fread(x, encoding = "UTF-8")))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `read_csv`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
cirium <- map_dfr(filenames, read_csv, locale = locale(encoding = 'UTF-8'))
```